# Does liquid work with wysiwyg editors? - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, liquid

I have just found liquid and watched the Railscasts on it. The video was pretty old but from watching it, it i can see liquid is what im looking for. Problem is I'm not sure if it will work with popular wysiwyg editor gems. I don't really want my users to be using plain input fields to make the templates.

I don't know if the wysiwyg editor has to be special to work with liquid or if liquid can basically work with any wysiwyg editor gem.

Are there recommended wysiwyg editor gems that work well with liquid or if that isn't a thing are there just normal editor gems that work with liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Please read this [blog](https://customer.io/blog/Email-wysiwyg-editor-inspired-by-jekyll.html). You can also use [newsly](https://github.com/ZmartGroup/Newsly) `gem` to manage your `liquid` template with `wysiwyg` editor. I used `ckeditor` in one of my application. It's quite easy to install.

Comment: I was looking at using ckeditor or wysiwyg editor gem https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor. Mainly wanted to know if it could be done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to parse the content and add your own data. The editor will not automatically figure out the variables and their values. The editor will save the content with tags and later you can parse it with Liquid

Here is an example form Liquid

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") # Parses and compiles the template
@template.render('name' => 'tobi')                # => "hi topi"
```

https://github.com/Shopify/liquid#how-to-use-liquid

And here is a blog post on how someone is using a wysiwyg with Liquid

https://customer.io/blog/Email-wysiwyg-editor-inspired-by-jekyll.html

Hope that helps